# How can we modify the scale of x and y axis in scatter plots in orange?

Tags: orange

I am new to Orange and using it for data visualization. I want to change the scale of x and y axis while plotting scatter plots. Can you please suggest how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can change scale by zooming in or out. Zoom in with the zoom icon. To zoom out, hold the right mouse button on the figure and drag mouse up or down.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The label values on the x axis are picked up automatically. I want specific unit for example x axis lables shows 0,2000,4000...... but I want it as 0,500,1000,1500,2000 and so on.... i want to customize the labels according to requirement. Can you please suggest how can it be done?